# expected primary-expression before '*' token

Tags: c++

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Хочу создать структуру из двух байтов и указателя на функцию, прикомпиляции выдает ошибку:

```
expected primary-expression before '*' token
```

в строке const struct TCommand tcIdentify = {opIdentify, 1, 
      &FInitConnection(quint8*buf)};

```
    #ifndef COMMANDS_H
    #define COMMANDS_H
    #include <QDataStream>

    //Коды команд
    #define opIdentify          0x01    //Идентификация прибора и протокола

    const struct TCommand* Commands[]={
    //    &tcIdentify,
    };


   class commands
   {
   public:
        commands();
        //функции выполнения команд
        struct TCommand{
          quint8 Code;  //Код команды
          quint8 BCnt;  //Кол-во фикс байт данных, которые нужно принять
          void (*Exec)(quint8*buf); //функция, вызываемая при вызове команды
        };
        quint8 * buf = new quint8;
        void FInitConnection(quint8 * buf);//установка соединения
        const struct TCommand tcIdentify = {opIdentify, 1, 
      &FInitConnection(quint8*buf)};

    };

    #endif // COMMANDS_H
```

Comment: И что вы хотели сказать этим `&FInitConnection(quint8*buf)`?

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно создать переменную типа `TCommand`, например `curCommand` и потом при совпадении `curCommand->Code` выполнить `curCommand->Exec(buf)`, пытаюсь объявить структурный тип и не получается, что-то недопонимаю.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуй убрать список аргументов

```
const struct TCommand tcIdentify = {opIdentify, 1, 
      &FInitConnection(quint8*buf)}
```

на

```
const struct TCommand tcIdentify = {opIdentify, 1, 
      &FInitConnection}
```

*Написал адрес результата вызова функции с аргументами. А надо адрес только самой функции.*

Comment: Во первых, адрес метода класса в С++ получается только при явном использовании оператора `&` и явном указании имени класса. Во-вторых, указатель в вопросе в принципе не может указывать на метод класса.

Comment: Адрес без аргументов я пробовал выдает ошибку `cannot convert 'void (commands::*)(quint8*) {aka void (commands::*)(unsigned char*)}' to 'void (*)(quint8*) {aka void (*)(unsigned char*)}' in initialization`

Comment: Всё понятно, в определении структуры указан элемент Exec типа указателя на СТАТИЧЕСКУЮ  функцию, а вы даёте адрес метода класса. (У метода класса, передаётся неявно аргумент this.) Вывод: или в определении структуры указывать тип ...(command::*Exec)(...) или сделать метод FInitConnection СТАТИЧЕСКИМ.

Comment: Спасибо, убрал аргументы и дописал в определении структуры. в итоге все скомпилировалось.